# communication between two flex apps

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, ipc, mxml

I have 2 flex apps on the same page. I want them to be able to call each other's public functions. I am thinking of using either externalInterface calls or FaBridge to do so.
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 76):

The best way to go is to use [`LocalConnection`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/LocalConnection.html). It allows you to call methods from a separate SWF without having to go through Javascript or a server.

Tip: if you're going to be sending arguments that are greater than about 20KB in size, you will want to split them up in two or more calls. In my experience `LocalConnection` calls have a limit of around that size for data.